# Automatic Logout after 15 minutes of inactive in php

Tags: php

I want to destroy session if users are not doing any kind of activity on website.
At that time after 5 users automatically redirect on index page. How is it possible?
Is possible in php with session handling and for that I have to maintain or update user login time or not..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is relatively easy to achive with this small snippet here:

```
 if(time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] > 900) { //subtract new timestamp from the old one
    echo"<script>alert('15 Minutes over!');</script>";
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['timestamp']);
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
    header("Location: " . index.php); //redirect to index.php
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time(); //set new timestamp
}
```

Comment: no prob, this should work, maybe you have to adjust some variables, i dont know what you use, but in general this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey! I have already this code on my logged in page `<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */
if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
 header("location:login.php");
 exit;
}
?>`. How shall i implement your code into my code? I tried to put it in a new line, but it turns out to say server error. Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: @Jornes The easiest way to implement this is to place this into the else branch of your condition. So it should look like `{ header("location:login.php"); exit; } elseif(time() - ...` At least i think so, guess i have to try it to actually say it for sure.

Comment: I tried! But, it doesn't work. Anything i need to amend in order to make it work? I tried to implement the code by following your said. But, it says server error too.

Comment: How can this work if the user is not navigating to any page? For PHP code to execute there has to be a server request. If the client should timeout and redirect when there is no request, it can only be done through JavaScript...

Comment: @ADTC that is true. PHP can only be used if you're using server requests. However, just translate that PHP Snippet into javascript, the logic is the same. Then put that snippet into a function and execute it every time the user does something. Then it should work without any flaws.

Comment: I think you mean to execute the JS repeatedly at some regular interval. If you rely on user doing something, it will not execute when the user left the computer or isn't doing anything. But yeah, there you have it. `:)`

Comment: @ADTC That doesn't matter. Why would you log him out when he's not doing something? The automatic logout is more of a security feature so you can leave your pc and no other person can access the website with your account data. Running that through an interval works too, but it's an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: @YUNOWORK what do you mean why I would log out the user when he's not doing something? Unless you can access the webcam and accurately monitor the person sitting in front of the computer, there's no way to tell the difference between _"person left the computer without logging out"_ and _"person is sitting in front of the computer doing nothing"_. Hence, just log out if the website is idle and the person is not firing any requests (ergo - user is not doing anything). Banking sites do that all the time. A few minutes of inactivity in-site and the session is logged out - no matter where I am.

Comment: `$_SESSION['timestamp']` has initial value of null (0) so you will end up with an infinite loop back to login.php as  if statement always is true (bigger than 900)

Comment: @Jornes the line where it says "header("Location: " . index.php);" is causing the error as index.php is not a variable. You need to use "header("Location: index.php"); instead.

Answer (score 38):

I got this solution from Sitepoint.com
Using a simple meta tag in your html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900;url=logout.php" />
```

> The 900 is the time in seconds that you want the session to be terminated if inactive.

Hope it works for you

**Edit: This method does not implement any other logic so will only work if you want to "force" logout** as said in the comments

Comment: Simple and effective! Great idea.

Comment: Where should I put the meta tag in. My php Code? Each page?

Comment: You coule have this in one file that you include in all your other files. Something like `include 'header.php'`

Comment: agreed with @MarkClark

Comment: Lets say I closed the browser after 10 minutes and opened it next day. This won't work then. Will it?

Comment: Evertime you open your browser this wiill restart

Comment: This logs you out even if you are using the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the code.

```
session_start();
$t=time();
if (isset($_SESSION['logged']) && ($t - $_SESSION['logged'] > 900)) {
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    header('location: index.php');
}else {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = time();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a cookie for a specific time.
For example you could put this on your login page:

```
<?php
  setcookie('admin', 'abc', time()+50); 
?>
```

Then in some file part that is included in every page, like 'header.php', you may include:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) {
  echo "<script> location.href='logout.php'; </script>";   
  }

  setcookie('admin', 'abc', time()+50);
?>
```

In the above example, after 50s the cookie will die and the user will be logged out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution Is
(i give you solution but this simple and syntax not been tried)

checkerOrCreatorTime.php

```
<?php
//if using the session, this additional advice me
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
session_start();
//create session (JUST FOR ONE TIME)
if (!isset($_SESSION['THE SESSION KEY FOR LOGIN (EX. USERNAME)'])){
    //create anyting session you need
    $_SESSION['user']['THE SESSION KEY FOR LOGIN (EX. USERNAME)'] = 'USER';
    $_SESSION['user']['TIME'] = '900';
}else
if (time() -$_SESSION['TIME'] > 900){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    // and whatever your decision
}
?>
```

Faq:

```
 1. Why use ['user'] is session login?
    if you using many session for user, you just unset one var, like this.

 2. why use a ini_set.... in this syntax?
    for more security
```

if you like using modern web, just using javascript for ajax

Comment: `$_SESSION['user']['TIME']`
That will set a separate variable for each user, however, the $_SESSION variable is already defined once per user, so you don't need to do this. Just do $_SESSION['TIME'] instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="frm"><input name="uname" type="text" placeholder="User Name" />
<input name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>
In index.php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['loggedAt'])) { header('dashboard.php'); } 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $name=$_POST['uname']; $pass=$_POST['pass']; 
if($name=="admin" &amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp; $pass=="1234") { 
session_Start(); $_SESSION['username']=$name; $_SESSION['loggedAt']=time(); header('location:dashboard.php?msg=Welcome to dashboard'); } } ?>
in dashboard.php
if(time() - $_SESSION['loggedAt'] > 240) { 
    echo"<script>alert('Your are logged out');</script>";
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['loggedAt']);
    header("Location: " . index.php);
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['loggedAt'] = time();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was included in the connection.php to ensure that the code is included in any page but you can implement on any page you want

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user-session']) OR isset($_SESSION['admin-session']) ) {
//then we are checking the activity sesssion $_SESSION['']
if (isset($_SESSION['last_active'])) {

    //if the time is set then we check the difference
    $max_time=5*60; #number of seconds
    $now=microtime(date("H:i:s"));
    //Checking the last active  and now difference in seconds
    $diff=round(microtime(date("H:i:s"))- $_SESSION['last_active']); #the difference of time
    if ($diff>=$max_time) { #if the difference is greater than the allowed time!
        //echo "logging out couse the time is".$diff;
        header("location:logout.php");          
    }else {
        $time=microtime(date("H:i:s"));
    $_SESSION['last_active']=$time; #Updating the time 
    //echo 'More time added the time was!'.$diff;
    }
}else{
    //if there is no last active then we create it over here
    $time=microtime(date("H:i:s"));
    $_SESSION['last_active']=$time;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using .htaccess

Add the below lines to your .htaccess file where 3600 is the number of seconds.
Sessions will automatically be destroyed after certain time has nothing to do with the activity or inactivity.

According to the below code session will be destroyed after 1 hour.

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600

php_value session.gc_probability 1

php_value session.gc_divisor 1
```