# implementing session time out before event in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am unable to implement this logic, how to perform a event (operation) before user session expire, for example:

user session time out: 20 mins

We need to store the user current time and his/her information to the database.
with in 19.59 sec time

it is possible how to implement this one

Note: Here Ideal time we taking for example after 19 mins user Browse the site time should be goes to next 20 mins not i mins

Last where the Codeigniter session time out redirecting logic have plz tell i saw the session library but i am not findout this logic where it have tell me i can implement this logic also

Comment: Never worked with codeigniter tbh, but i already wrote a plainsimple php snippet which accomplishes this task, maybe its usable for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516969/automatic-logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive-in-php/20517030#20517030

Comment: 19.59  plz check it i updated

Comment: @user2964881 You need to extend the *[Session](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php)* core library and override the [`sess_write()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L135) method by changing the **[lines #178-182](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L178-L182)**.  Put your logic right before [`$this->sess_destroy();`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L180). Good luck!

Comment: Please help friends i did not completed till now pending this issue

Answer (score 0):

In the Libraries directory, make a file called MY_Session.php

Open up the Session core library, copy the sess_write function.

Paste that into the file you just created (MY_Session.php). Just before $this->sess_destroy(), insert your code to log whatever you need to log into your database.