# PHP Online/Offline Script

Tags: php

I'm trying to code a script where a person logs in, and his last login time stamp is updated to the table. If he has logged in for more than 1 hour, immediately log him out even if he was interacting. I wonder how would I do that? I am using time() function to store the login time like this:

```
$lastlogin = time();
```

This has been marked duplicate: [Automatic Logout after 15 minutes of inactive in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516969/automatic-logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive-in-php)

But no, this is different. I want that to happen automatically without the user having to refresh the page. The answer on that question will only execute if the user interacts to the site, but I want the user to get logged out even if the user is away and not interacting.

Comment: I suppose you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516969/automatic-logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive-in-php/20517030#20517030

Comment: No that will only logout the user when he/she refreshes the page and the PHP code will be re-executed. I want them to automatically logout and redirect to index.php after x amount of minutes even if they are away.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I want it to automatically work even if the user is not on the site and has just left without logging out. :l

Comment: The thing is, PHP is not doing anything "automatically". Its doing something when its called, it cant execute itself. The only thing i can think of is a cronjob whos executed every hour and calls a specific PHP script which is logging out everyone whos inactive for an hour. But even then you will need to save the `$lastlogin = time()` in a database. Maybe you can use cookies too which expire after 1 hour. It sounds pretty complicated. Is there a reason why you want it to happen automatically?

Comment: Yeah, I want to learn how it works automatically in many popular sites. And no, I read somewhere that cronjob is not required always. How would you implement the cookie way? It will be really appreciated if you share the code. And yes that $lastlogin is inserted to the database as soon as a user logs in.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with PHP alone. You'll need something on the workstation to implement the logout there. A simple Javascript timer would do the job, I suppose. You could look at a Server-sent event to control the logout, but you'd need to implement an event handler in Javascript, and you'd need to set up the connection on every page.

Comment: And a variable called $lastlogin in the class also is assigned.

Comment: @MikeW Can you tell me how? I'm new to JavaScript. :l

Comment: Most of the popular sites are using cookies if im not completely wrong. The cookie expires after a specific time of beeing inactive and the user has to login again.

Comment: Setup a Javascript which polls the server every 10-15 sec..do the logic appropriately..if you find a user inactive for an hour,  then redirect them to logout page

Comment: @YUNOWORK are cookies vulnerable to hacking? Like can hackers edit cookies and gain higher priviledges?

Comment: Cookies dont grant privileges in your case, so the worst thing they can do is keep them logged in. You should just make sure that you validate the content of it, since it comes from a user.

Comment: @YUNOWORK would it still not require a user to reload the page to update the database?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf You've been downvoted because your question is 'unclear, not useful, or shows no research effort' (I paraphrase). It's clear from the comments that you have no idea how to implement this, so the question is too broad to be a good fit for [so]. I expect it to be closed on that basis before long.

Comment: @MikeW I expect a good solution, not a specific.

Comment: this question is not duplicate of what you marked. but its a bit broad. please look at sockets http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php and AJAX, im just pointing to a direction, i hope someone with experience on these can answer it for you

Comment: Oh my god sockets! Arent they used to make shells?

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem via jQuery. Currently making an algorithm on how will I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when the user logs in, you save the login time (`time()`) in a `$_SESSION` variable. Then, before any action is taken, you check for

```
if (time() >= $_SESSION["login_time"]+3600) {
    //Log the user out
}
```

3600 is the number of seconds in an hour, so you're basically checking "Is *now* later than *time when the user logged in* plus *one hour*?". And if that is true, you log the user out.

The reason this is put in a session is because if the session itself expires, your user is logged out regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand fully your want, but give you simple,

this just simple php for check you login, this example you user $_SESSION['USER'] for checking user login and set in this session array's
and in this set is:

```
$_SESSION['user']['THE SESSION KEY FOR LOGIN (EX. USERNAME)'] = "User"
$_SESSION['user']['time'] = "900"
```

And this validation:

```
<?php
session_start();
//create session (JUST FOR ONE TIME)
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['THE SESSION KEY FOR LOGIN (EX. USERNAME)']) and time() -$_SESSION['user']['TIME'] > 900){
     unset($_SESSION['user']);
     echo "logout"
    }
?>
```

in client you must create Ajax to validation, i recommend if you dont fully understand, you just use ajax from jQuery in you page,

```
<script src"{YOUR JQUERY PLACE}">
setTimeout(function(){
$.ajax({
   url:"checker.php",
   dataType:"html",
   type:"GET",
   success:function(html){
      if(html == "logout"){
      //whatever you want..
      //window.location.reload(); for reload you page,
      }
   }
});
}, 3000); // this check from client for server every 3 second
</script>
```

and in you page you must validation again by PHP, this idea is, Server set time for user, in client PC, you script request to your server for checking this user. if user time's more than 15 mnt, this php send to server for refresh your browser and in you php for all page, you must give syntax logout if user time's more that 15 mnt.