# php redirect when idle not redirecting

Tags: header, location

I found the following script at https://thisinterestsme.com/expire-php-sessions.

This code is used to check if user is inactive for a period
logout and direct to login screen.

**problem**

Redirect does not happen. Redirect happens only when page is refreshed.

**script**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

      <?php  $inactive = 30;
    $_SESSION['inactive']=$inactive;

    if( !isset($_SESSION['timeout']) )
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $inactive; 

   $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
   $_SESSION['life']=$session_life;

 if  ($session_life > $inactive)
   {  session_destroy();
     echo '<script>';
     echo 'console.log("You have been logged-out!");';
     echo 'window.location.href="login.php"'; 
echo '</script>';
}
$_SESSION['timeout']=time(); 
 ?>
```

Redirect happens only when I refresh the page

instead of `echo 'window.location.href="login.php"'` I tried`header("Location: login.php")` but no success (NO auto redirect to "login" page ).

What shall I do so that the page will be redirected without refresh?

I am using PDO+ php 7

I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516969/automatic-logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive-in-php/20517030) and tried this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900;url=login.php" />
```

But this does not check whether "idle" or NOT.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried JQUERY to auto refresh DIV (say #refreshDIV) and check the idle time.This works. but program (login.php) is display in the said i.e. refreshDIV. I want to open for the in main browser...pls help

Answer (score 0):

I wish to share the complete answer.

1. Check whether idle for 30 seconds (15 minutes). If yes (idle for 30 seconds) destroy the session. Here's a code snippet to be cut and paste on top of web page:

```
<?php  

session_start();
 
 if (!isset($_SESSION['loginid']))
    {
    
     header("Location: login.php");
     }

     // store inactive time
        $inactive = 30;
        $_SESSION['inactive']=$inactive;

        if( !isset($_SESSION['timeout']) )
         $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $inactive; 

       $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
       $_SESSION['life']=$session_life;

     if  ($session_life > $inactive)
       {  session_destroy();
           unset($_SESSION['loginid']);
           header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $_SESSION['timeout']=time(); 
?>
```

2. Check whether idle for more than 30 seconds. Here's jQuery code (cut and paste in common sharing file normally used with Include_once("xxxx.php").

```
$(function(){
    function refreshDiv(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkidletime.php'
        }).done(function(result) {
            $('#refreshDIV').html(result);
            window.setTimeout(refreshDiv, 5000);
        });

    }
    window.setTimeout(refreshDiv, 5000);
});
```

3. Checkidletime.php called by above function refreshDiv (part of include file):

```
session_start();
      
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
      
    if ($session_life > $_SESSION['inactive'] )
    {   unset($_SESSION['loginid']);
     ?>
     <script>
    location.reload();/* refresh page
    </script>
     <?php
       
    }
```